# Map-Reduce with a wait

Tags: mapreduce

The concept of map-reduce is very familiar. It seems like a great fit for a problem I'm trying to solve, but it's either missing something (or I lack enough understanding of the concept).

I have a stream of items, structured as follows:

```
{
  "jobId": 777,
  "numberOfParts": 5,
  "data": "some data..."
}
```

I want to do a map-reduce on many such items.
My mapping operation is straightforward - take the jobId.
My reduce operation is irrelevant for this phase, but all we know is that it takes multiple strings (the "some data..." part) and somehow reduces them to a single object.

The only problem is - I need all five parts of this job to complete before I can reduce all the strings into a single object. Every item has a "numberOfParts" property which indicates the number of items I must have before I apply the reduce operation. The items are not ordered, therefore I don't have a "partId" field.

Long story short - I need to apply some kind of a waiting mechanism that waits for all parts of the job to complete before initiating the reduce operation, and I need this waiting mechanism to rely on a value that exists within the payload (therefore solutions like kafka wouldn't work).
Is there a way to do that, hopefully using a single tool/framework?
I only want to write the map/reduce part and the "waiting" logic, the rest I believe should come out of the box.

**** EDIT ****
I'm currently in the design phase of the project and therefore not using any framework (such as spark, hadoop, etc...)
I asked this because I wanted to find out the best way to tackle this problem.

Comment: By default, reducers already wait for individual mappers to finish. You should not share state between them... Besides, it's unclear if you're using Spark or Hadoop or something else

Comment: @OneCricketeer edited according to your comment

Answer (score 0):

"Waiting" is not the correct approach.

Assuming your jobId is the key, and `data` contains some number of parts (zero or more), then you must have multiple reducers. One that gathers all parts of the same job, then another that processes all jobs with a collection of parts greater than or equal to `numberOfParts` while ignoring others